# calculate total price of product for different attribute

Tags: magento2, configuration

I am new to magento and trying to calculate total price of any configurable product in magento 2,and I am struggling with it.

Suppose I have two dropdown attribute as following,

**1. Paper size**

```
Option     Price
A4         1$
A3         2$
2. Color option
```

Option           Price
black & white    1$
colored          2$
Result would have been something like:

```
If someone selected,
paper size =    A4
color option =  black & white
total price = 1+1 = 2$

If someone selected,
paper size =   A4
color option =  colored
total price = 1+2 = 3$

similarly,if,
paper size =   A3
color option =  colored
total price = 2+2 = 4$
```

But the total price looks something different than i have expected. And there would be more drop down attribute like this. Did i make something wrong ? Is there any better way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out this myself after i got idea from [here](https://mconnectmedia.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/magento-2-product-types-explained-with-examples/)

Steps are:

```
1. Create a new bundle product
2. select ship bundle item option "together"
3. click "create new option" then "add products"
4. select the products you want to add to the bundle
5. save the product
```